# Eclipse is running a wrong java file

Tags: java, actionlistener, mouselistener

I am trying to run this code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingHoles extends JFrame{

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel{
        private Point[] points;
        private int count = 0;
        
        public MyPanel() {
            points = new Point[100];
            
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    points[count] = (new Point(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            
        }
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int a = 0;
            while(a != -1) {
                if(a%3 == 0)
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                else if(a%3 == 1)
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                else if (a%3 == 2)
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < count - 1;i++) {
                g.drawOval(points[i].x, points[i].y, 50, 50);
                g.fillOval(points[i].x, points[i].y, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
        
    public DrawingHoles() {
        setSize(400,300);
        setTitle("drawing circles with your mouse");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new MyPanel());
    }
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        (new DrawingHoles()).setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

So I can draw red-green-blue circles in order by clicking on the panel like in the image here.
[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZphQ.jpg)

but it keeps running another code that I wrote right before writing this code above.

I think the file name and stuff are right but I have no idea why it wouldn't run

Comment: can you please send an image of your eclipse configuration?

Comment: How would this code run at all? `int a = 0; while(a != -1) {...}` without assigning `a` to -1 is an infinite loop. Your code becomes trapped inside that `while` and will never leave. So if you don't see it draw as many things as you expected: that's not too surprising. Start by removing the `while (a != 0) {` line, and its associated closing bracket: that while shouldn't be there at all (and neither should that `int a=0` but that's a different problem that you can probably figure out on your own).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wVPPBUt it just runs another code like this

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking inside this class and chose run as java program. If you are clicking on the run button which is on top menu that might be selecting a default class as an entry point.